# Select the cell and press Enter (Run-time error 1004)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, enter

I want to select a cell and press Enter. Tried to write the code , but the error in a line ( book1.Worksheets("6").Range("Q100").Select) jumps out .

```
    Sub example()
    Dim book1 As Workbook

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Ïðîåêò ñòàâêè\Ïîèñê ðåøåíèÿ\Óñîâ 
    6\ñåçîí äëÿ ïðîãè\Àíãëèÿ\1-îå ìåñòî\6.xlsm")

    book1.Worksheets("6").Range("Q100").Select
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure your worksheet name is "6" ? maybe you mean the index ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, Worksheet name is 6 (100%)

Comment: why do you need to press Enter in a cell?

Comment: Is the cell protected?

Comment: @YowE3K, the cell is not protected

Comment: Is sheet "6" the active sheet?

Comment: @jsotola , I am trying to solve the problem in another way

Comment: what is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @jsotola , updating UDF , but you know that

Comment: use the F8 key to step through the code. stop when the yellow highlight gets to the line that ends with _.Select_. then go to the worksheet and click cell Q100 and press Enter. if you are unable to do it manually, then the program will not be able to either.

Comment: you made no mention of UDF until now, how could i possibly know? i bet that your mechanic really loves you when you bring your car in for repair. mechanic: what is wrong with your car? you: oh, you know.

Comment: you are trying to recalculate the worksheet?

Comment: What has selecting a cell and pressing enter got to do with updating a UDF?!?

Comment: @jsotola , incredible joke

Comment: @maxim465 is sheet "6" the active sheet?

Comment: @YowE3K, i was wrong , because Selecting a Cell ,Selecting Formula row ,  then press Enter only update UDF

Comment: @YowE3K , it is not active sheet , i change it and program do fine , but did not solve my main problem .Thank you !

Comment: **What has this question got to do with a UDF?**  I am completely confused.  I thought the error was to do with you selecting a cell on a non-active sheet.

Comment: trying to uncover the real issue here

Comment: @YowE3K, do you have any hair left?

Comment: @YowE3K, you are absolutly write .Thanks for help !

Comment: If this is somehow some attempt at getting a UDF to always recalculate, just include `Application.Volatile` in the function.  (Obviously you will need to force a calculation once in order for the `Application.Volatile` line to be executed, but after that it will run whenever any recalc of the workbook is done.)

Comment: @jsotola Much to my hairdresser's disgust, yes. (She always threatens to charge me extra to resharpen her scissors because she says it is too thick!)

Comment: @jsotola ,
For a person who has a little knowledge of programming, my past question would be banal, this is clearly not your case

Comment: @YowE3K , Wow ! Now all works .I included (Application.Volatile) in function ,but did not know about this (Obviously you will need to force a calculation once in order for the Application.Volatile line to be executed, but after that it will run whenever any recalc of the workbook is done.) 
You solve my main problem . Thank you very much !

Comment: Ahhh - "past question" - now I understand.  @maxim465 People don't always look up your profile to see what you have asked in the past.  Each question should stand by itself.  (I will add my comment about ensuring you have calculated the cell once before expecting it to be treated as Volatile to your previous question where it belongs, then VTC it.)

Comment: now it all makes sense ... pull a few teeth ...